# Merge multiple column values and group it based on id

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

My data table looks like this:

```
    ╔════════╦══════════════╦════════════╦
    ║BatchID ║ CreateUser   ║ ChangeUser ║         
    ╠════════╬══════════════╬════════════╬
    ║      1 ║ xxx          ║    yyy     ║ 
    ║      1 ║ zzz          ║    zzz     ║
    ║      2 ║ aaa          ║    aaa     ║
    ║      3 ║ bbb          ║    Null    ║
    ║      4 ║ ccc          ║    ddd     ║                              
    ╚════════╩══════════════╩════════════╩
```

Say I want to make a new column that gives the distinct user with comma separator.

I want it looks like this eventually

```
    ╔════════╦══════════════╦
    ║BatchID ║ UserName     ║        
    ╠════════╬══════════════╬
    ║      1 ║ xxx,yyy,zzz  ║ 
    ║      2 ║ aaa          ║ 
    ║      3 ║ bbb          ║ 
    ║      4 ║ ccc,ddd      ║
    ║        ║              ║                              
    ╚════════╩══════════════╩
```

How should I write the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LISTAGG function -

```
SELECT BatchID , LISTAGG(CreateUser, ',') UserName
  FROM (SELECT BatchID, CreateUser
          FROM YOUR_TAB
         WHERE CreateUser IS NOT NULL
        UNION
        SELECT BatchID, ChangeUser
          FROM YOUR_TAB
         WHERE ChangeUser IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY BatchID
```